# android Fragment - in which method i need to retrieve data from sqlite and populate to recylerview

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I had downloaded the data from server and i insert into database
i had 200 rows in sqlite and it is taking time to load
it strucks the fragment 
in which method i need to retrive the data and populate to recylerview

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Index your search and JOIN columns.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onActivityCreated() method , create a arrayadapter and populate the listview.
Makesure you are downloading data from server in background thread, use asynnctask.